# cakephp text hepler's truncate method not giving correct result

Tags: php, cakephp

Hi I am using cakephp text helpers  truncate method to display text string with only required length.

```
echo $this->Text->truncate('my text with more than 500 characters ',10,array('ellipsis' => $this->Html->link('   Read More',$link,array('class'=>'readMore','target'=>'__blank')),
'exact' => true));
```

Here I have given length as 10 but still it is showing me full result (i.e whole string and concatenates 'Read more ' link last  of that).  but when I gives $length value more than 100 it works fine(gives me result as a string with 100 characters).

is this cakePHP helper logic bug or am I using it wrong ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not pass HTML helper content to "ellipsis", the HTML helper results in a long string which already exceeds 10 characters.